# Билиотека записи файла, определенной структуры. C++

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, makefile

Разделила файл на несколько структур. Описала эти структуры в заголовочном файле и описала функцию записи файла.

function.h

```
 struct Station 
{ 
   std::string station_name; 
   std::string rec_dew; 
   std::string year;
};
struct InfaboutChanell
{ 
    int chanellcount;
    int analogChanell;
    int discretChanell;
};
struct InfAnalogChanel
{ 
    int id;
    std::string chanell_id;
    std:: string ph;
    std::string ccmb;
    std::string UU;
    double a;
    double b;
    double skew;
    double min;
    double max;
    double Primery;
    double Secondary;
    std::string SP;  
};
struct InfDiscretChanel
{
    int DN;
    std::string ch_id;
    std::string ph;
    std::string ccmb;
    int y;
};
void writeCfgFile ();
```

function1.cpp

```
  void writeCfgFile(){
     Station station;
     ofstream file("fileConfiguration.cfg");

file<<station.station_name<<","<<station.rec_dew<<","<<station.year<<"\n";

           //The information about analog channels
           vector<InfAnalogChanel> s;
           InfAnalogChanel a;
           InfAnalogChanel b;

           a.id=1;
           a.chanell_id="ток ф А";
           a.ph="";
           a.ccmb="";
           a.UU="A";
           a.a=1.290489E-01;
           a.b=0;
           a.skew=0;
           a.min=-32767;
           a.max=32767;
           a.Primery=3000.00000000;
           a.Secondary=1.00000000;
           a.SP="P";

           b.id=2;
           b.chanell_id="ток В";
           b.ph="";
           b.ccmb="";
           b.UU="A";
           b.a=5.139708E-02;
           b.b=0;
           b.skew=0;
           b.min=-32767;
           b.max=32767;
           b.Primery=3000.00000000;
           b.Secondary=1.00000000;
           b.SP="P";

           s.push_back(a);
           s.push_back(b);

           for(size_t i=0;i<s.size();++i)
               file<<s[i].id<<","<<s[i].chanell_id<<","<<s[i].ph<<","<<s[i].ccmb<<","<<s[i].UU<<","<<s[i].a<<","<<s[i].b<<","<<s[i].skew<<
               ","<<s[i].min<<","<<s[i].max<<","<<s[i].Primery<<","<<s[i].Secondary<<","<<s[i].SP<<"\n";

           //The information about discret chanells
           vector<InfDiscretChanel> discret;
           InfDiscretChanel first;
           InfDiscretChanel sec;

           first.DN=1;
           first.ch_id = "Раб МТЗ";
           first.ph="";
           first.ccmb="";
           first.y=0;

           sec.DN=2;
           sec.ch_id = "3_3";
           sec.ph="";
           sec.ccmb="";
           sec.y=0;

           discret.push_back(first);
           discret.push_back(sec);

           for(size_t i=0;i<discret.size();++i)
               file<<discret[i].DN<<","<<discret[i].ch_id<<","<<discret[i].ph<<","<<discret[i].ccmb<<","<<discret[i].y<<"\n";     
    }
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    writeCfgFile();

    };
```

Я так понимаю, что правильно, чтобы данные записывались в main.cpp. А функция writeCfgFile() записывала их в  определенную структуру.
нужно получить библиотеку. Но для начала правильно ее описать.
Подскажите, как сделать? Подробнее, пожалуйста

Comment: не понял какая библиотека вам нужна, можно по-подробнее?

Comment: Мне нужно создать библиотеку, которая будет записывать полученные данные в файл, определенного формата

Comment: А код для библиотеки есть? Ести есть, то просто компилируете как -shared и подключаете к программе. Или это не то, что вам надо?

Comment: Ввод имени файла необходимо сделать вне библиотеки, а не зашивать его внутри :   void writeCfgFile(char *){

Comment: А остальное для учебного задания пойдет )

Comment: Допустим, я собрала эти файлы с помощью makefile в библиотеку. Делала в linux. Получила libWritefile.so, как мне проверить ее? подключить к проекту? вот я зависла вообще, не могу понять. Дали задание собрать библиотеку и проверить как она работает

Comment: Andrej Levkovitch, это и есть мой код

Comment: Почему метка стоит Visual Studio, если у Вас линукс?

Comment: ну проект я пишу в Visual Studio, а собрать библиотеку нужно в линуксе, кое что меняю, и собираю библиотеку.

Comment: да, и если собираете с помощью `make`, то это лучше указывать (добавлять соответствующую метку) и, заодно, приводить код из вашего `make`, где вы собираете библиотеку и подключаете ее к исполняемому файлу

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте это: https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/zlp/ - не смотрите, что указано "Си", это то, что вам нужно. Смотрите сразу про библиотеки.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76994/discussion-on-answer-by-andrej-levkovitch-----).

Answer (score 0):

Хочу получить такие строки. Написала функцию.
Помогите довести ее до ума

fileConfiguration.cfg

```
1,ток ф А,,,A,1.290489E-01,0,0,-32767,32767,3000.00000000,1.00000000,P
2,ток В,,,A,5.139708E-02,0,0,-32767,32767,3000.00000000,1.00000000,P
```

function.h

```
class InfAnalogChanel
{ 
public:
   int id;
   std::string chanell_id;
   std::string ph;
   std::string ccmb;
   std::string UU;
   double a;
   double b;
   double skew;
   double min;
   double max;
   double Primery;
   double Secondary;
   std::string SP;
};
void writesecondline (std::ostream &file, InfAnalogChanel const &iac);
```

function1.cpp

```
void writesecondline(std::ostream &file, InfAnalogChanel const &iac){
           ofstream file("fileConfiguration.cfg");

       }
```

main.cpp

```
InfAnalogChanel a = {1,"ток ф А",,,"A",1.290489E-01,0,0,-32767,32767,3000.00000000,1.00000000,"P"};
  InfAnalogChanel b = {2,"ток В",,,"A",5.139708E-02,0,0,-32767,32767,3000.00000000,1.00000000,"P"};

  ofstream file("fileConfiguration.cfg");
  writesecondline(file, a);
  writesecondline(file, b);
```